# iCarousel: How to center images vertically in customized uiview

Tags: ios, center, icarousel

in my screen (viewController A), I have a customized tab-bar at the bottom, so all the images are not centered vertically. However, when I go to a modal view and then go back to the viewController A, all images are centered. Can you explain the situation? And can you give me the solution to center all images in the first time viewController A appears?
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Of course in the function: - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view, I set view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
EDIT: Since after dismissing a modal view controller, all images are centered vertically, my current solution is that: When view controller A first appears, I present the modal view controller and then dismiss it without animation. This action is done transparently without users's notice and give the result I want. However, this solution is the not best choice apparently. It's best if I know the right way to set the images centered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the method -setViewpointOffset?

```
iCarousel.viewpointOffset = CGPointMake(0, targetOffset);
```

Comment: It should be iCarousel.viewpointOffset = CGSizeMake(0, targetOffset); ? I put it in viewDidLoad in viewController A, and yes, it change the position of images vertically. However, if I use this method, when I go to a modal view and then dismiss the modal view, the images will not centered.

Comment: Have you done something in -viewWillAppear or -viewDidAppear methods? Or have you modify some ivars in ViewController A when the model VC is presented? Also, if you repeat to present the model VC, will the images keep going up?